# radio buttons value change based on MySql Data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am retrieving data from MySql with PHP. Everything works fine but not with the radio buttons. What I would like to do is that as the text boxes values change, I would also like to change the value of the check box but leaving some check boxes values intact. Here are the codes:

HTML:

```
 <select id="userDropdown"></select>

   <label>Name</label>
   <input type="text" id="name" />

   <label>Phone</label>
   <input type="text" id="phone" />

 **<p>
   M:<input type="radio" class="flat" name="gender" id="gender" value="M" checked="" required />
   F:<input type="radio" class="flat" name="gender" id="gender" value="F" />
 </p>**
```

Javascript

```
//sql data...
var data = [
    {username: 'User 1', name: 'Bill', phone: '123-456-789', gender: 'male'},
    {username: 'User 2', name: 'John', phone: '123-456-987', gender: 'male'},
    {username: 'User 3', name: 'Mary', phone: '123-654-789', gender: 'female'}
];

var dropdown = $('#userDropdown');
dropdown.append('<option value="" >Select User</option>');
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var item = data[i];
    dropdown.append('<option value="' + item.username + '" >' + item.username + '</option>');
}

$('#userDropdown').change(function(){
    var user = this.value;
    var dataItem = $.grep(data, function(e){ return e.username == user; });

    if(dataItem.length > 0){
        $('#phone').val(dataItem[0].phone);
        $('#name').val(dataItem[0].name);
        $('#gender').val(dataItem[0].gender);
    }
});
```

Comment: and what is the problem? It seems that your code is doing what you want. Can you explain the problem more in depth?

Comment: it does not. if you run the code, it will only change the values of the textboxes but not the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the duplicate id and make it easy. HTML5 id specification [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

HTML:

```
<p>
   M:<input type="radio" class="flat" name="gender" id="gender-male" value="M" checked="" required />
   F:<input type="radio" class="flat" name="gender" id="gender-female" value="F" />
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
if(dataItem.length > 0){
    $('#phone').val(dataItem[0].phone);
    $('#name').val(dataItem[0].name);
    $('#gender-'+dataItem[0].gender).prop('checked', true);
}
```

You can see it work in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/weq4ajua/)

Comment: No luck with this one still.

Comment: then there has to be something wrong with some other part of your code, I have added fiddle to the answer

Comment: yeah. it worked with fiddle. will this be true if the the gender value is either 0 or 1 on my database?

Comment: I just replaced the value with numbers rather than male and female and everything works in fiddle but not mine.

Comment: It did it. I was really thinking hard about this all night and discovered that it is with my css class. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your input radio values like this (with "male" and "female") to match with your sql data :

```
<p>
   M:<input type="radio" class="flat" name="gender" id="gender" value="male" checked="" required />
   F:<input type="radio" class="flat" name="gender" id="gender" value="female" />
</p>
```

Then change this line :

```
$('#gender').val(dataItem[0].gender);
```

like this :

```
$("input[name=gender][value=" + dataItem[0].gender + "]").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

or like this (since jQuery 1.6) :

```
$("input[name=gender][value=" + dataItem[0].gender + "]").prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: no luck with this. All other values change but not with the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do in your `change` function:

```
dropdown.change(function () {
    var user = this.value;
    var dataItem = $.grep(data, function (e) {
        return e.username == user;
    });
    if (dataItem.length > 0) {
        var $m_input= $('input[name="gender"][value="M"]');
        var $f_input= $('input[name="gender"][value="F"]');

        if(dataItem[0].gender === "male"){
            $m_input.prop('checked', true);
            $f_input.prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $m_input.prop('checked', false);
            $f_input.prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This did not work either. All other values change but not with the radio buttons.